# Detecting silence moments in an mp3 file to pause a second mp3 file when 1st is silenced

Tags: python, audio, mp3, pydub

sorry by advance for my english, i'll try to be as clear as possible.

I am trying to create a script, that would add an mp3 file of a radio background noise (VUHF like).
With PyDub, i managed to overlap 2 files to add a noise effect to any vocal audio to make it feel like a uhf radio record.
With uhf coms, there is noise only when someone broadcasts on the frequency.
I would need my script to detect silent moments to pause the background noise and make it play again when someone talks.

Thanks for your help,

Jules.

I tried to use split_on_silence but seems like it's only supposed to remove silenced moments.

Comment: You may find pydub's [`silence.detect_silence`](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#silence) helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.